# Spring security - Не работает POST метод

Tags: spring, post, spring-security

Не работает POST запрос в Spring Security.

**SecurityConfig**

```
package com.myfilter.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomFilter newFilter;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(newFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)

                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/login", "/").permitAll()
                
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()

                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
    }


}
```

**CustomFilter**

```
package com.myfilter.security;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String email = httpServletRequest.getParameter("email");


        System.out.println(email);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Посмотреть этот проект на github** https://github.com/romanych2021/MyFilter

Comment: Что значит "Не работает"? Наверное ошибку какую-то кидает? Если да - приведите лог оной

Comment: Выдаёт null. Нет ни каких ошибок. Просто выдаёт null. Даже при попытке получить HttpMethod ничего нет, как бы ничего не приходит через POST метод. Хотя Spring Security вылавливает логин и пароль для авторизации, а они приходят через POST

Comment: **View this project at github** [https://github.com/romanych2021/MyFilter](https://github.com/romanych2021/MyFilter)

Comment: Переведите вопрос полностью на русский язык

Comment: @dIm0n – **Не работает POST запрос в Spring Security.** То есть, если, если делать запрос методом POST и попытаться что то от туда выловить, то не получится, потому что он не работает. Ну он как бы работает и в тоже время не работает. Например Spring Seurity вылавливает свои свои параметры. А вот остальные параметры невозможно вытащить. Ошибок нет. Просто NULL

Comment: Заголовок и последнее предложение не переведены. Используйте кнопку править

Comment: @dIm0n – **Поправил**